# Recommendations for a JSON editor on Windows?

Tags: json, editor, formatter

Are there any JSON editors on Windows?

- I tried Notepad++, but it only supports JSON with third party plug-ins which need to be called from Notepad++'s menus each time you open a JSON file. And some of them do not work properly.
- I tried Gedit for Windows, but it does not support JSON by default. I could not find support for the Windows version.
- Most of the JSON services I found are Internet-based (used from the browser). I cannot use them offline.
- All JSON extensions for browsers (Chrome and Firefox) can only read (format or validate) the JSON file. I could not find any JSON editor extensions. I don't want to use extensions because most of them (all the extension that I have tried) do not work with local files. They are only enabling themselves when I download a JSON file from the Internet.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: JSONBuddy seems to be another interesting JSON editor with syntax-coloring and well-formed checking You can download a trial version from Download.com: http://download.cnet.com/JSONBuddy/3000-2247_4-75946118.html?tag=mncol;1

Comment: Here is one at [json-editor.htm](http://www.xml-buddy.com/json-editor.htm) which also supports JSON syntax-coloring, auto-completion and syntax checking.

Comment: This show how "backwards" moderation is on this site. "closed as not constructive" -- really??

Comment: Come on, this is actually legitimate question. Why is it "not constructive"? There's barely any good JSON viewer for Windows....

Comment: I wish it could be possible to down-vote administrator's decisions

Comment: I've found Notepad++ with the plugin JSTool suiting my needs. http://www.sunjw.us/jstoolnpp/

Comment: I'm craving for the answer, the question is very detailed & reflects what I currently need.

Comment: Plus it looks like closing the question caused the OP to grow disheartened and abandon the site :-(  Anyone still looking should ask at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ where this sort if question is actively encouraged.

Comment: Why in the world is this Closed? How is this non-constructive? And why has it not been opened back yet? Anyways, here's something I found useful: https://github.com/RSuter/VisualJsonEditor/releases

Comment: I like Stackoverflow but this measures (that its not an isolated case), forces  me to lurk more and share less.

Comment: Shouldn't it be just moved to http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: I was recently made aware of Visual Studio Code: https://code.visualstudio.com/ which gives you nice syntax-coloured json (as long as the filename suffix is ".json") and a 'miniaturized whole file' view that is handy for those larger json documents, plus source-control (e.g. github) integration.